# Replace numbers by a calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I would like to know if there's a way in javascript to replace **[0]** by 
a calculation : **[+1]** and **[-1]**

Example of my situation :
I have a gallery presenting 6 images, I want to use keyboard arrows to navigate.
When the current image is the 4th, if I let **[1]** in my script to go to the previous image by pressing keyboard arrow, the first image appears instead of the third.
Any idea ? Thanks.

Script :

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            $('.prev')[0].click();
            break;

        case 39:
            $('.next')[0].click();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: No sure I get it, but you could have a variable, say `index` and add 1 or substract 1 depending on your case. and use that `index` instead of `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store current position

```
var current = 0;
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            $('.prev')[--current].click();
            break;

        case 39:
            $('.next')[++current].click();
            break;
    }
});
```